# Automatically obtain new token after it expires

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api, react-props

So, here I'm making a request to obtain an api token which I use it in the login function after that. That token expires in one hour which make the website stop working. What I want is to obtain a new token automatically after one hour when it expires to handle the expiry of the old token, and also to override the token saved in the session storage. btw I'm not using Redux here.

```
componentDidMount(){
      let url1 = ``;

        fetch(url1,{
          method: 'POST'
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({authToken: responseJson.auth_token}, ()=>{
            sessionStorage.setItem('auth-token', this.state.authToken);
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
```

Comment: You could call this method when specific token expired error occurs, may be inside a catch error block.. When you say website stops working, not clear what it means.. May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940355/3254405

Comment: Or token expires because it’s desired this way when user session ends and user is required to login again, then token will be reset..

Comment: With stops working I mean if I'm getting data from the api and then I refresh thw page of something the data doesn't come back as the api token was expired. And yes but what I want to achieve is to obtain a new api token automatically while the user is logged in and just make him continue what he is doing without having to login again.

Comment: May be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50563034/3254405 or https://medium.com/shoutem/keeping-your-api-tokens-fresh-72059a7b0586?source=messageShare-cde74a5c1784-1538168938

Comment: @Gazzar2 are you aware of token expiry duration in your API response?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean but the token as I mentioned expires after on hour

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at below code where fetch the userToken after every 59mins assuming you said token expiry is 1hr in your question. 
What we do is make the call to fetchToken as soon as the component mounts and start a timer which will repeat this call after 59 mins. Once the component unmounts we clean up and clear the timer. (Note: 59 min is just an assumption, you can fetch the token anytime before expiry)

```
componentDidMount(){
    let url1 = ``;
    this.fetchToken();
    this.refetchTokenId = setInterval(this.fetchToken, 59 * 60 * 1000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.refetchTokenId)
}

fetchToken = () =>  {
    fetch(url1,{
        method: 'POST'
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({authToken: responseJson.auth_token}, ()=>{
            sessionStorage.setItem('auth-token', this.state.authToken);
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```